# Unable to SSH into DigitalOcean droplet which was created by "docker-machine" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssh, permissions, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have created a `DigitalOcean` droplet using `docker-machine` command. Now, I am unable to login from my local machine to droplet because my ssh key is not added to `server`. 
I have used the following command to create droplet

```
docker-machine create --driver=digitalocean --digitalocean-access-token=MyToken --digitalocean-size=1gb  --digitalocean-backups=true --digitalocean-ssh-user=root myapp
```

I created the droplet from my local machine. I have added my local access key to droplet as well but I am still unable to login.

I am using the following command to ssh

```
ssh root@droplet-ip-address
```

I have tried to access `droplet` from `digitalocean` console as well but it does not allowed me to copy/paste ssh key.

Is there any other way to solve this issue?
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `--digitalocean-ssh-key-fingerprint` parameter to docker-machine to tell it which SSH key to use.

See the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/digital-ocean/#options) for details.

Comment: I can `build` image  and  `up` my app using `docker-compose` command. I just want to login into the terminal using `ssh` command. Each time I run `ssh root@droplet-ip` it show me the following error `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: That's why you need to add the extra parameter to tell it to install the ssh key in the droplet.

Comment: yes, but the problem is it runs with ` docker-machine create` command as a parameter. But the droplet is already created. I just want to add ssh key.

Comment: Why not just re-create the droplet with the ssh key?

Comment: The server is already  `up` with `database` and all other services. It is difficult now to stop server and recreate new `droplet` with same configurations